# How to change expo name in location alert

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

simple question.
I want to change the "**EXPO**" name inside the allow location message, where should I make it.

[image: Check Image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mohammad Reza Farahani's answer is correct in part. But in my case the problem solved itself after changing using expo app to the real app.

Answer (score 1):

"**Expo**" name displayed in the message is the name of your application name. To change the name of your app, edit the "**Display Name**" field in Xcode:

[image: Check Below Image]

For Android, change the 'app_name' string in `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`.

To change the message shown below the title ("Allow Expo experiences...") you can override it using the `ios.infoPlist` key in `app.json`. To change your location permission you need to change the "infoPlist" to the following:

```
"infoPlist": {
  "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Allow MyApp to use your location"
},
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay and thank you for your answer, but it's not working. The answer is correct but the name changed after changing from using expo app to use the real app

Comment: This answer is correct. I just want to add that some users might have to use keys such as "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" and/or "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" based on methods used.